# how to copy data from two tables to the third if there are several conditions that are interconnected?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 3 tables.

1. Table_one

| brand | model | generation | engine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| audi | q3 | 2011 | ph25 |
| audi | q5 | 2011 | ph25 |
| audi | rs | 2012 | tz15 |
| bmw | i3 | 2011 | dd37 |
| mini | cooper | 2016 | pkn11 |

2. Table_two

| name | parent |
| --- | --- |
| ph25 | 3 |

3. Table_Categories

| id | name | parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2. | audi | 1 |
| 3. | q3 | 2 |
| 4. | 2011 | 3 |
| 5. | bmw | 1 |
| 6. | i3 | 5 |
| 7. | 2011 | 6 |

How to formulate an sql query so that, based on the data of the tables “Table_one” and “Table_Categories” in “Table_two” in column “name” were inserted engines, in column “parent” were inserted id of it’s generation?
(Its necessary to pay attention, that id of generations in third table connected with model’s id in third table)

Comment: Provide definite data (w/o '...') and desired output for this data strictly. [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), pp. 5 and 3.

Comment: There are more than 850 lines instead of “…”

Comment: Create fake sample data, 5-10 rows.

Comment: Added four lines

Comment: Well.. where is desired output for shown data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to interpret your question but I think I understand what you are asking for -

```
INSERT INTO `Table_two` (`name`, `parent`)
SELECT `t1`.`engine`, `c1`.`id`
FROM `Table_one` `t1`
JOIN `Table_Categories` `c1`
    ON `t1`.`generation` = `c1`.`name`
JOIN `Table_Categories` `c2`
    ON `c1`.`parent` = `c2`.`id`
    AND `t1`.`model` = `c2`.`name`;
```